# Why does a pandas Series of DataFrame mean() fail, but sum() does not, and how to make it work?

Tags: python, pandas

There may be a smarter way to do this in Python Pandas, but the following example should, but doesn't work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0], [1, 2], [2, 0]], columns=['a', 'b'])
df2 = df1.copy()
df3 = df1.copy()

idx = pd.date_range("2010-01-01", freq='H', periods=3)
s = pd.Series([df1, df2, df3], index=idx)
# This causes an error
s.mean()
```

I won't post the whole traceback, but the main error message is interesting:

```
TypeError: Could not convert    melt  T_s
0     6   12
1     0    6
2     6   10 to numeric
```

It looks like the dataframe was successfully sum'med, but not divided by the length of the series.

However, we *can* take the sum of the dataframes in the series:

```
s.sum()
```

... returns:

```
      a     b
0     6   12
1     0    6
2     6   10
```

Why wouldn't `mean()` work when `sum()` does? Is this a bug or a missing feature? This does work:

```
(df1 + df2 + df3)/3.0
```

... and so does this:

```
s.sum()/3.0
      a  b
0     2  4.000000
1     0  2.000000
2     2  3.333333
```

But this of course is not ideal.

Comment: Unclear if it should work at all but you could apply the function: `s.apply(pd.DataFrame.mean)`

Comment: This just gives the mean of each constituent data frame.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you define `s` with

```
s = pd.Series([df1, df2, df3], index=idx)
```

you get a Series with DataFrames as items:

```
In [77]: s
Out[77]: 
2010-01-01 00:00:00       a  b
0  1  0
1  1  2
2  2  0
2010-01-01 01:00:00       a  b
0  1  0
1  1  2
2  2  0
2010-01-01 02:00:00       a  b
0  1  0
1  1  2
2  2  0
Freq: H, dtype: object
```

The sum of the items is a DataFrame:

```
In [78]: s.sum()
Out[78]: 
   a  b
0  3  0
1  3  6
2  6  0
```

but when you take the mean, [`nanops.nanmean` is called](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/nanops.py#L258):

```
def nanmean(values, axis=None, skipna=True):
    values, mask, dtype, dtype_max = _get_values(values, skipna, 0)
    the_sum = _ensure_numeric(values.sum(axis, dtype=dtype_max))
    ...
```

Notice that `_ensure_numeric` ([source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/nanops.py#L660)) is called on the resultant sum.
An error is raised because a DataFrame is not numeric.

Here is a workaround. Instead of making a Series with DataFrames as items,
you can concatenate the DataFrames into a new DataFrame with a [hierarchical index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html):

```
In [79]: s = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], keys=idx)

In [80]: s
Out[80]: 
                       a  b
2010-01-01 00:00:00 0  1  0
                    1  1  2
                    2  2  0
2010-01-01 01:00:00 0  1  0
                    1  1  2
                    2  2  0
2010-01-01 02:00:00 0  1  0
                    1  1  2
                    2  2  0
```

Now you can take the `sum` and the `mean`:

```
In [82]: s.sum(level=1)
Out[82]: 
   a  b
0  3  0
1  3  6
2  6  0

In [84]: s.mean(level=1)
Out[84]: 
   a  b
0  1  0
1  1  2
2  2  0
```

Answer (score 9):

You could (as suggested by @unutbu) use a hierarchical index but when you have a three dimensional array you should consider using a "[pandas Panel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html)".  Especially when one of the dimensions represents time as in this case.

The **Panel** is oft overlooked but it is after all where the name pandas comes from. (Panel Data System or something like that).

Data slightly different from your original so there are not two dimensions with the same length:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 3]], columns=['a', 'b'])
df2 = df1 + 1
df3 = df1 + 10
```

Panels can be created a couple of different ways but one is from a dict.  You can create the dict from your index and the dataframes with:

```
s = pd.Panel(dict(zip(idx,[df1,df2,df3])))
```

The mean you are looking for is simply a matter of operating on the correct axis (axis=0 in this case):

```
s.mean(axis=0)

Out[80]:
          a         b
0  4.666667  3.666667
1  4.666667  5.666667
2  5.666667  3.666667
3  5.666667  6.666667
```

With your data, `sum(axis=0)` returns the expected result.

**EDIT:**  OK too late for panels as the hierarchical index approach is already "accepted".  I will say that that approach is preferable if the data is know to be "*ragged*" with an unknown but different number in each grouping.  For "*square*" data, the panel is absolutly the way to go and will be significantly faster with more built-in operations.  Pandas 0.15 has many improvements for multi-level indexing but still has limitations and dark edge cases in real world apps.

Comment: You're right that computation on the panel is significantly faster than on the hierarchical dataframe. But what are the extra built-in operations that panels have that dataframes don't? `set(dir(pan))-set(dir(df))` did not turn up anything interesting. Also, can you elaborate on the "limitations and dark edges cases" to which you referred?

Comment: This is my fault for asking two questions in one. I will be using your solution for my problem since, as you point out, the `Panel` solution is the correct one for the example I gave. But I think @unutbu addressed the full question of what exactly is keeping my original series-based code from working. I very much appreciate your insight! Both of these should be in the docs!

Comment: I want to also add, that unlike the hierarchical index version, you can now also do `s_mean = np.mean(s, axis=0)`, or sum, std, or I'm guessing any numpy function that works on arrays.